# Efficient way of finding the minimum/maximum row index for each column in a numpy.array with nonzero value?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, min

I have a 2D numpy array `iarr` coming from a single color of a picture.

I want to find the minimum/maximum row index in each column with a nonzero value. If there are no nonzero values in a column this column doesn't need to be considered. 
I have a working solution but it is very slow. My current solution is this

```
img = Image.open('nameofimage.jpg')
iarr = numpy.array(img)[:,:,0]

nonz = numpy.nonzero(iarr)
colinds = numpy.unique(nonz[1])
minrowinds = numpy.array([numpy.min(nonz[0][nonz[1]==cind]) for cind in colinds])
```

Comment: You want `np.argmax` for this

Comment: @yatu Thank you, worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to yatu's pointer, I can now answer this myself.

```
colinds = numpy.unique(nonz[1])

minrowinds = numpy.argmax((iarr>0),axis=0)[colinds]
```

For the maximum indices I had to flip the array first, as `np.argmax` always gives the first occurrence of the maximum value.

```
maxrowinds = numpy.argmax(numpy.flip((iarr>0),0),axis=0)[colinds]
maxrowinds = iarr.shape[0] - maxrowinds
```